# Battery Run-time/capacity calculation

Tags: batteries, battery-operated, robotics, power-consumption

Problem is to find the *difference* in **run-time** between:

a. Using ***12V 10Ah*** battery vs ***24V 5Ah*** battery.

PS: Load is rated at 12VDC and 24V to 12V step-down conversion is available.

Comment: The biggest difference is the output impedance.to load impedance ratio.  Not all loads are fixed R’s like batteries, light bulbs, motors etc. The buck regulator will also lose 10% efficient typ.

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist Thanks. Yet, my confusion is whether using above mentioned batteries have any effect in battery run-time if I prefer former or latter?

Comment: In theory the 12V battery will draw less power and be more efficient, if you compare Wh for each at a C rating but the voltage is better regulated with a step down but current limited

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist Thanks a lot. Lastly, if suppose I have a load rated at 12V 10A, then run-time for 10Ah / 5Ah battery will be 1 Hr in both the cases. Is it so?

Comment: If load is 10A at 12V and 6.5A at 24V due to switching losses? Not quite

Comment: You must define actual current vs V and V cutoff to ensure it never undercharges

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist Thank you. I assumed Wh is same for both batteries, then power draw will be equal considering 100% efficiency!

Comment: Buck regulators from 24V to 12V are not 100% efficient and are poor for low ESR reactive loads. Also all batteries are derated to 1hr load from 20h rating by at least 30% for SLA

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist Thanks again!  I want to end this discussion by considering the example: Supposedly a load consumes 500 Wh for 'x' hrs, then if I chose 12V battery, capacity comes around 41.67Ah or 20.83 Ah at 24V. Which will you prefer and why?

Comment: I would choose neither and pick a battery with the lowest Peukert's constant towards 1 which varies from 1.2 to 1.6  This can be computed based on the battery specs and curves at different rates

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist Need your valuable feedback on this. Thanks! https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/400425/battery-capacity-measurement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The amount of **energy** in both batteries is the same:

- 12 V * 10 Ah = 120 Whr
- 24 V * 5 Ah = 120 Whr

Instead of **run-time** we generally use the term **discharge time**.

If you discharge both (fully charged) batteries with the same amount of **power** then you will get similar discharge times.

Examples:
- load the 12 V battery with 1 A, that's 12 V * 1 A = 12 W; 120 Whr/12 W = 10 hours
- load the 24 V battery with 0.5 A, that's 24 V * 0.5 A = 12 W; 120 Whr/12 W = 10 hours

Note how I loaded the 24 V battery **with half the current**. That's **crucial** and often forgotten by those who only look at the Ah rating of a battery but for get about the **voltage**. The 24 V battery is loaded by 0.5 A (instead of 1 A) because I want to discharge using the same amount of **power** from each battery.

If I use a step-down DCDC converter in combination with the 24 V battery to get 12 V then I would have to load that 12 V also with 1 A to get the same 12 W discharge load. The DCDC converter will then draw 0.5 A at 24 V (I'm assuming it is an ideal, loss less DCDC converter), same as in my example above.

It is a well known property of DCDC down converters that the input current can be lower than the output current if the input voltage is higher than the output voltage. It has to be as input power and output power are equal.